# Why is this variable combination outputting an answer with 2 backslashes?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that is like logging onto a computer, in the way that you can create an "account" and the computer will remember your password for later. (So you couldn't just use a simple variable)

So, the program works by asking you to choose to create an account or sign in. (I have some of the code ready for if the user chose to create an account, but I'll add it later once I have the signing in part done.) The way that i'm choosing to store the username and password is by using a text document. The username will be the name of the text document, (ex. D:\username.txt) and the password would be whats written in the text document.

```
import os
import sys
import fileinput


def signin():
    username = input("Username:\n>>")
    UsernameandPasswordfile = "D:\%s.txt" % username
    password = "Password:\n>>"
    print(UsernameandPasswordfile)
    file = open(UsernameandPasswordfile, "r+")
    for line in fileinput.input(UsernameandPasswordfile):
        if password in line:
            print("signed in!")
        else:
            print("error")

question = input("sign in or create new account?\n>>")
if question == "sign in":
    signin()
```

And here is the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\document.txt'
```

I have a test document called "document". so, If I were to run my program using "document" as my username, it should find the file. But instead it isn't, because it keeps adding in an extra backslash to the file location, which of course makes the location wrong. What can I change to fix that?

Comment: If your document is called "document" then why are you telling it to look for "document.txt"?

Comment: because that is its name

Comment: I thought you said it was called "document". Which is correct?

Comment: The backslashes are not the problem.

Comment: On windows, you really need double backslash to identify a path, so this is not the problem.

Comment: then why won't the computer find and recognize the file

Comment: Because it does not exists. I just tried your code without changes, just on my computer and changing the path from D:\ to D:\tests\. Test 1 without a file created said `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\tests\\some.txt'` but test 2 after creating such file manually gave no error. **Edit:** As per the deleted comment, I think you believe D:\ is the desktop... and that's the issue.

Comment: so is there anything i can do to make it work?

Comment: Are you creating the txt file at desktop and not at D:\?

Comment: yes, at my desktop

Comment: The desktop isn't _D:\_, it's usually _C:\Users\CJPeine\Desktop\_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the comments, your issue is that you are asking to check if the file at D:\ exists, but you are creating that file at your desktop. Those are two different places.

Desktop is not located at the root of a hard drive like **D:\**. Desktop is usually located at something like **D:\Users\CJPeine\Desktop** (depends on your user) so you need to first find where is your desktop located.

The easier way to find where your .txt is (the commonly known *path* of a file), is by right-clicking on the file and selecting properties option. Find the path or location information there.

Then you just need to change the next line to find the file accurately.

```
UsernameandPasswordfile = "D:\Users\CJPeine\Desktop\%s.txt" % username
```

**On backslashes:**
However, that would create a problem. Some characters like `\n` or `\t` (among others) create special behaviour, which is why we need to escape them. For example `\n` adds a new line so if you write:

```
"this is a te\nst"
```

The result is:

```
this is a t
est
```

So in order to fix that we escape those characters by adding a double backslash instead of just one. Adding that pretty much means "don't try to find an special behaviour for my backslash". And in the end the working code is.

```
UsernameandPasswordfile = "D:\\Users\\CJPeine\\Desktop\\%s.txt" % username
```

Comment: when i tried that it gave me the error:  UsernameandPasswordfile = "D:\Users\CJ Peine\Desktop\%s.txt" % username
                             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Double backslashes, my bad. That is needed because some characters like `\n` create different behaviour. `\t` is a tabulation and \n adds a new line. In order to avoid adding such issues, we use \\ to escape the unicode characters.

Comment: and it says: C:\Users\CJ Peine\Desktop

Comment: so what do i change?

Comment: I updated my answer. Just add a double \\ for each folder.

Comment: folder? I'm haven't used any folders.

Comment: Okay, wait for a second to understand it. Desktop IS inside some folders. C: is the hard drive. Users is a folder, CJ Peine is another folder, Desktop is inside that one. So C:\Users\CJ Peine\Desktop means your desktop (and everyones) is inside 2 or 3 folders. Get why you couldn't find the file before?

Comment: I got this error:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Users\\CJPeine\\Desktop\\passwords.txt'

Comment: one thing to consider is that i am using pycharm. And in the past it has automatically created and used a file within pycharm to edit. Do you think that that is the problem?

Comment: I just updated my answer... again. Follow it carefully as it should explain everything. Pycharm shouldn't give you such an issue.

Comment: Also note that I written CJPeine after Users as an example, I don't know your computer's username. And don't remove spaces if it haves.

Comment: you have been saying that the path start with a 'D' (D:\Users\CJPeine\Desktop\%s.txt)

Comment: but my path starts with a "C" (C:\Users\CJ Peine\Desktop)

Comment: does that make a difference?

Comment: I though it was obvious that the path was made up as an example, as it's impossible for me to know the real pathing. It was your job to find the right pathing. I said D because you said D (check your own code at the top). Seems like now you finally learnt how to find it. Yes, it makes a huge difference.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to accept a correct answer and upvote using the controls at the left side of each answer.

Comment: Did you want me to check the green check for you? cause i did

Comment: Thanks ^^. And please inform yourself or google about pathing, it will probably clear some answers. For example the main letter (C: or D:) pretty much means they are different hard-drives.

Answer (score 0):

From running it, I don't see any issues with this code. It works fine when the file is there. Make sure the file is there and you are looking at the right drive.

Comment: would the file be there if i created the text document on my desktop?

Comment: You have to create the file at the path you provide  to open().